# Laravel 5.5 task scheduler does not seem to be looping through all of my commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a lot of cron tasks (below) which are supposed to be ran at various times. It does not seem to me that these tasks are all running... I run the command 'php artisan schedule:run' every minute set up on my forge server. My schedule function houses the following commands:

```
        $schedule->call(function () 
        {
            Log::info('SCHEDULER RAN AT: ' . Carbon::now());
        })->cron('* * * * *');
        $schedule->command('WelcomeMessages:send')->cron('* * * * *');

        $schedule->command('FirstDaySurveysEST:close')->cron('59 3 * * *');
        $schedule->command('FirstDaySurveysCST:close')->cron('59 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('FirstDaySurveysPST:close')->cron('59 6 * * *');

        $schedule->command('DailySurveysEST:close')->cron('59 3 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysCST:close')->cron('59 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysPST:close')->cron('59 6 * * *');

        $schedule->command('DaysEST:add')->cron('0 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DaysCST:add')->cron('0 5 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DaysPST:add')->cron('0 7 * * *');

        $schedule->command('HelpSurveysEST:reset')->cron('1 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('HelpSurveysCST:reset')->cron('1 5 * * *');
        $schedule->command('HelpSurveysPST:reset')->cron('1 7 * * *');

        $schedule->command('DailySurveysEST:reset')->cron('2 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysCST:reset')->cron('2 5 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysPST:reset')->cron('2 7 * * *');

        $schedule->command('DailySurveysEST:create')->cron('3 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysCST:create')->cron('3 5 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysPST:create')->cron('3 7 * * *');

        $schedule->command('PicSurveysEST:create')->cron('4 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('PicSurveysCST:create')->cron('4 5 * * *');
        $schedule->command('PicSurveysPST:create')->cron('4 7 * * *');

        $schedule->command('TransitionSurveysEST:create')->cron('5 4 * * *');
        $schedule->command('TransitionSurveysCST:create')->cron('5 5 * * *');
        $schedule->command('TransitionSurveysPST:create')->cron('5 7 * * *');

        $schedule->command('PicSurveysEST:send')->cron('0 0 * * *');
        $schedule->command('PicSurveysCST:send')->cron('0 1 * * *');
        $schedule->command('PicSurveysPST:send')->cron('0 3 * * *');

        $schedule->command('DailySurveysEST:send')->cron('0 14 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysCST:send')->cron('0 15 * * *');
        $schedule->command('DailySurveysPST:send')->cron('0 17 * * *');

        $schedule->command('TransitionSurveysEST:send')->cron('1 22 * * *');
        $schedule->command('TransitionSurveysCST:send')->cron('1 23 * * *');
        $schedule->command('TransitionSurveysPST:send')->cron('1 1 * * *');

        $schedule->command('TransitionRemindersEST:send')->cron('1 22 * * *');
        $schedule->command('TransitionRemindersCST:send')->cron('1 23 * * *');
        $schedule->command('TransitionRemindersPST:send')->cron('1 1 * * *');

        $schedule->command('RemindersEST:send')->cron('0 22 * * *');
        $schedule->command('RemindersCST:send')->cron('0 23 * * *');
        $schedule->command('RemindersPST:send')->cron('0 1 * * *');

        $schedule->command('Encouragement7EST:send')->cron('0 18 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement7CST:send')->cron('0 19 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement7PST:send')->cron('0 21 * * *');

        $schedule->command('Encouragement14EST:send')->cron('0 20 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement14CST:send')->cron('0 21 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement14PST:send')->cron('0 23 * * *');

        $schedule->command('Encouragement21EST:send')->cron('0 16 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement21CST:send')->cron('0 17 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement21PST:send')->cron('0 19 * * *');

        $schedule->command('Encouragement28EST:send')->cron('0 17 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement28CST:send')->cron('0 18 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement28PST:send')->cron('0 20 * * *');

        $schedule->command('Encouragement35EST:send')->cron('0 21 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement35CST:send')->cron('0 22 * * *');
        $schedule->command('Encouragement35PST:send')->cron('0 0 * * *');
```

Some of these commands are doubled up, so is that an issue?

All of these commands run through an array of the participants and then executes a function should they meet certain criteria... so the functions could take a bit and potentially run over top of each other...

I know that they pull the correct users. When I manually enter these functions they work as intended.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, are you encountering any errors? Do you have any exceptions thrown on your log file?

Comment: No, I don't... what I am asking is - Will all these tasks running at the same time lead to some tasks not being run? Due to overlap?

Comment: What makes you think they aren't running? Try writing a log entry at the beginning of each command, before doing anything else, and see if (and if so, which) any of the commands don't run.

Comment: Well, they do run, and I have such a command in there... but this is a SMS texting survey, kind of worried I am overloading the SMS app with informaton